# Setting First input type date value as the min date value of the second input date type in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, date, calendar

I have two input type date fields and I need to make the selected date of the first input date type as the minimum date of the second input date type. How can I achieve this? Please find my existing code.

```
<html>
<input type="date" ng-model="date1" required/>
<input type="date" ng-model="date2" required/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code snippet to achieve the requirement.

```
<html>
<input type="date" ng-model="date1" required/>
<input type="date" ng-model="date2" required min="{{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"/>
</html>
```